# Airflow Google Authentication does not work as expected

Tags: airflow, google-authentication

I followed the step provided in the document: https://airflow.apache.org/security.html#google-authentication

After following all steps and restarting the webserver. I do not see any difference with login page and it still asks me for password authentication. I am not sure how to get the google signin option on the web page. I do not get any error on webserver logs.

```
Configuration=> airflow.cfg:
authenticate = True
#auth_backend = airflow.contrib.auth.backends.password_auth
auth_backend = airflow.contrib.auth.backends.google_auth

[google]
client_id = <client id>
client_secret = <secret key>
oauth_callback_route = /oauth2callback
domain = <domain_name>.com
```

Comment: You may have already done this, but you need to ensure you are using the (new in 1.10.0, default in 1.10.3) FAB-based frontend. I find the UPDATING.md very helpful when chasing down new features: https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/UPDATING.md#new-webserver-ui-with-role-based-access-control

Comment: Thanks @7yl4r. Does it means that with RBAC set to true, we cannot enable google authentication?

Comment: The opposite; you must have `rbac = True` in `airflow.cfg` in order to use this auth method and you must be using airflow `1.10+`. Consider including this airflow.cfg detail and your airflow version in the question.

Answer (score 8):

So I discovered that if we used `webserver_config.py` as described above, there's no need to add the `[google]` section in `airflow.cfg` anymore. It's just redundant. To sum up, my setup is:

airflow.cfg:

```
authenticate = True
auth_backend = airflow.contrib.auth.backends.google_auth

rbac = True
```

webserver_config.py:

```
from flask_appbuilder.security.manager import AUTH_OAUTH

AUTH_TYPE = AUTH_OAUTH

AUTH_USER_REGISTRATION = True

AUTH_USER_REGISTRATION_ROLE = "Admin"

OAUTH_PROVIDERS = [{
    'name':'google',
    'whitelist': ['@yourdomain.com'],  # optional
    'token_key':'access_token',
    'icon':'fa-google',
    'remote_app': {
        'base_url':'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v2/',
        'request_token_params':{
            'scope': 'email profile'
        },
        'access_token_url':'https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token',
        'authorize_url':'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth',
        'request_token_url': None,
        'consumer_key': '<your_client_id>',
        'consumer_secret': '<your_client_secret>',
    }
}]
```

I have to use `AUTH_USER_REGISTRATION_ROLE = "Admin"` for the very first user otherwise that user cannot even log in and end up in an error page saying "too many redirects".

Comment: I found that in 1.10.4 I still needed `[google] auth_callback_route = /oauth2callback` - without this logging in works but first takes me to a crash page requiring me to edit the URL to proceed.

Comment: My only guess is you didn't set up the callback in the Google developer console

Comment: The too many redirects seems to occur when the default role only gives a user `Public` permissions

Comment: after searching all day this is finally the setup configuration I have been looking for. The airflow documentation not calling out the need to create/update webserver_config.py is really annoying.

Answer (score 4):

As I had RBAC enabled, so I had to change webserver_config.py file for oauth to work with RBAC. webserver_config.py file is created once we have RBAC enabled to true and restarting web server.

1. AUTH_TYPE = AUTH_OAUTH (to enable Google authentication/Github authentication)
2. OAUTH_PROVIDERS must be set example: https://github.com/dpgaspar/Flask-AppBuilder/tree/master/examples/oauth
3. AUTH_USER_REGISTRATION = True
4. AUTH_USER_REGISTRATION_ROLE = "Already defined roles/Admin/Public"

Once we have it configured and web server restarted, google sign in option appears at the login page. 
For reference: https://flask-appbuilder.readthedocs.io/en/latest/security.html?highlight=google#authentication-oauth